# How can I automate updating my SQL Server database?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I get multiple text files daily to update my database from my client side and I am not a DBA expert. Every day I update it manually. Is there any method I can use to make this easier? I think there is a way to automate it but I don't know exactly what to do.

Comment: What database?? SQL Server, Oracle, MySql?  The options differ based on the product.  (and of SQL Server, which version)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to create SQL Job task that will be executed within a specific time. The job schedule time can be configured easily. Take a look at this tool http://www.mssqltips.com/tip.asp?tip=1083.

Answer (score 1):

MSSQL answer: If you can get the files automatically (residing on a share, ready to copy, ...) you can use SSIS to create a package that does the required stept and then schedule it with SQL Server Agent.

General answer: You can automate repeating tasks, specific way to do this differs at least as much as the involved product names.